# Vistalizator - Uninstall language that crashed the system

Tags: windows-7, windows, language, language-pack

Recently, I tried to install a language using Vistalizator. I installed the required updates, changed the language and restarted my computer. The computer didn't boot up, so I had to restore my system to a system restore point. The language i was trying to install is English. After restoring my system, the bootscreen was set to English, but the rest of my computer was just my old language (Dutch). Later I downloaded a language-file (.cab) and tried to install it using "Install or Uninstall a display language". But i got an error: `Language already installed`.

I am using Windows 7 Home Premium, Service Pack 1.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're using a third-party application to change a feature that Microsoft has locked down and does not intend to be changed. Any time you do that, you risk causing unintended troubles for yourself. It may work sometimes, but it appears this time that it did not. I would recommend contacting the application developers for support on this issue.

Comment: Windows 7 Home Premium does not official support installing language packs.  That was a feature of Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: i know, but i found a program called "Install or Uninstall a display language". That program is now gone, because i uninstalled the language in Vistalizator. Gonna ask a new question about it...